# SQL Conditional Statement in Where Clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, where-clause, conditional-statements

I would like to write the following IF statement in SQL. Most of the where clause is constructed, but it's the condition around the statement that I'm struggling with:

```
if @StuYear = 11 then

AND (@TeachingGroup = 'Select All')
AND ([DataCollection] = @DataCollection)
AND ([Name] = @SubjectName) 
AND (@Subgroup='Select All') 
AND '' = CASE @subjectName WHEN 'English' THEN KS2en WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN KS2ma ELSE KS2av END 
AND Result Not Like '[ABU]%' AND Result <> ''

else if @StuYear = 10 then 

AND @TeachingGroup Not Like 'Select All' 
AND ([DataCollection] = @DataCollection) 
AND ([Name] = @SubjectName) 
AND ([TeachingGroup] = @TeachingGroup)  
AND @Subgroup='Select All' 
AND '' = CASE @subjectName WHEN 'English' THEN KS2en WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN KS2ma ELSE KS2av END 
AND Result Not Like '[ABC]%' AND Result <> ''

end if
```

Comment: So what happens if you replace `if` with `where` and `else if` with `or` and surround the other conditions in paranthesis?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hi again Tim. The problem is when I change the value of DataCollection it brings though additional random results.  The results should match because other than the Results column the data in the different DataCollection is the same.

Comment: `AND Result Not Like  'A*'  AND Result Not Like 'A'  AND Result Not Like 'B' AND Result Not Like 'U' AND Result Not Like ''` can be written much more concisely as `Result NOT IN ('A*','A','B','U','')`

Comment: @MartinSmith31 it does have to be a like though, does the same apply. I have for example A+, A and A-.

Comment: Why does it have to be `LIKE`? You aren't using any wildcards so it is the same as `=`. Only reason I can think you would have to use `LIKE` here would be if the datatype of the column is `text` (in which case it shouldn't be)

Comment: @MartinSmith hi. They should be wildcards, my omission.

Comment: After the edit `AND Result  Not Like  'A*%' AND Result  Not Like  'A%' AND Result Not Like 'B%' AND Result  Not Like  'C%' AND Result  Not Like ''` is the same as `AND Result Not Like '[ABC]%' AND Result <> ''`

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks Martin, that looks way better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply   replace `if` with `where` and `else if` with `or` and surround the other conditions in paranthesis:

```
...
where (@StuYear = 11 
AND (@TeachingGroup = 'Select All')
AND ([DataCollection] = @DataCollection)
AND ([Name] = @SubjectName) 
AND (@Subgroup='Select All') 
AND '' = CASE @subjectName WHEN 'English' THEN KS2en WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN KS2ma ELSE KS2av END 
AND Result Not Like  'A*' 
AND Result Not Like 'A' 
AND Result Not Like 'B' 
AND Result Not Like 'U' 
AND Result Not Like '' )

OR (@StuYear = 10 
AND @TeachingGroup Not Like 'Select All' 
AND ([DataCollection] = @DataCollection) 
AND ([Name] = @SubjectName) 
AND ([TeachingGroup] = @TeachingGroup)  
AND @Subgroup='Select All' 
AND '' = CASE @subjectName WHEN 'English' THEN KS2en WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN KS2ma ELSE KS2av END 
AND Result  Not Like  'A*' 
AND Result  Not Like  'A' 
AND Result Not Like 'B' 
AND Result  Not Like  'C' 
AND Result  Not Like '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer helped point me in the right direction. However, I eventually resolved the issue by applying the year condition within the where clause as opposed to rapping it around them:

```
where 
    (@StuYear = [stuyear]
    AND @TeachingGroup = 'Select All'
    AND [DataCollection] = @DataCollection
    AND [Name] = @SubjectName
    AND @Subgroup='Select All'
    AND '' = CASE @subjectName WHEN 'English' THEN KS2en WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN KS2ma ELSE KS2av END
    AND ((Result Not Like '[ABU]%' and result not like '' and stuyear='11')
            or(Result Not Like '[ABC]%' and result not like '' and stuyear='10')
            or(Result Not Like '[ABCD]%' and stuyear='9'))
    AND Result <> '')
OR 
    (@StuYear = [stuyear]
        AND @TeachingGroup Not Like 'Select All'
        AND [DataCollection] = @DataCollection
        AND [Name] = @SubjectName
        AND [TeachingGroup] = @TeachingGroup
        AND @Subgroup='Select All'
        AND '' = CASE @subjectName WHEN 'English' THEN KS2en WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN KS2ma ELSE KS2av END
        AND ((Result Not Like '[ABU]%' and result not like '' and stuyear='11')
                or(Result Not Like '[ABC]%' and result not like '' and stuyear='10')
                or(Result Not Like '[ABCD]%' and stuyear='9'))
        AND Result <> '')
```